# CUDA out of memory

Tags: nlp, pytorch, named-entity-recognition, bert-language-model

I am getting error when trying to run BERT model for NER task.
"CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 3.82 GiB total capacity; 2.58 GiB already allocated; 25.38 MiB free; 6.33 MiB cached)I have also tried reducing batch size to 1c

```
enter code here
epochs = 10
max_grad_norm = 1.0

for _ in trange(epochs, desc="Epoch"):
    # TRAIN loop
    model.train()
    tr_loss = 0
    nb_tr_examples, nb_tr_steps = 0, 0
    for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        # add batch to gpu
        batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
        b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch
        # forward pass
        loss = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None,
                     attention_mask=b_input_mask, labels=b_labels)
        # backward pass
        loss.backward()
        # track train loss
        tr_loss += loss.item()
        nb_tr_examples += b_input_ids.size(0)
        nb_tr_steps += 1
        # gradient clipping
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(parameters=model.parameters(), max_norm=max_grad_norm)
        # update parameters
        optimizer.step()
        model.zero_grad()
    # print train loss per epoch
    #print("Train loss: {}".format(tr_loss/nb_tr_steps))
    # VALIDATION on validation set
    model.eval()
    eval_loss, eval_accuracy = 0, 0
    nb_eval_steps, nb_eval_examples = 0, 0
    predictions , true_labels, true_inputs = [], [],[]
    for batch in valid_dataloader:
        batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
        b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch

        with torch.no_grad():
            tmp_eval_loss = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None,
                                  attention_mask=b_input_mask, labels=b_labels)
            logits = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None,
                           attention_mask=b_input_mask)
        logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
        label_ids = b_labels.to('cpu').numpy()
        inputs = b_input_ids.to('cpu').numpy()

        true_inputs.append(inputs)
        predictions.extend([list(p) for p in np.argmax(logits, axis=2)])
        true_labels.append(label_ids)

        tmp_eval_accuracy = flat_accuracy(logits, label_ids)

        eval_loss += tmp_eval_loss.mean().item()
        eval_accuracy += tmp_eval_accuracy

        nb_eval_examples += b_input_ids.size(0)
        nb_eval_steps += 1
    eval_loss = eval_loss/nb_eval_steps
    pred_tags = [tags_vals[p_i] for p in predictions for p_i in p]
    valid_tags = [tags_vals[l_ii] for l in true_labels for l_i in l for l_ii in l_i]
    valid_inputs = [[idx2word[l_ii] for l_ii in l_i] for l in  true_inputs  for l_i in l ]


    print("F1-Score: {}".format(f1_score(pred_tags, valid_tags)))
    print("Validation loss: {}".format(eval_loss))
    print("Validation Accuracy: {}".format(eval_accuracy/nb_eval_steps))
```

Attached is the output of nvidia-smi:-

[nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFsLT.png)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to allocate 100% of your memory. The GPU needs a bit of that memory to keep track of software, and if it is plugged to the screen, to show you this stackoverflow page. So even if you have 25Mb free, allocating 20Mb of those can be risky

Comment: Hey,so do you have any suggestion how can I reduce allocation

Comment: I don't think it's possible. BERT is such a large network. Sorry about that!

Comment: You probably need a GPU with more than 4GB of VRAM. In my experience you always get an error from cuda claiming to need a few more Mb when you run out of memory. In reality you probably actually need much more. I think this is an artifact of how pytorch allocates memory from the GPU.