# Getting Cuda Out of Memory while running Longformer Model in Google Colab. Similar code using Bert is working fine

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, attention-model

I am working on text classification using Longformer Model. I took even just first 100 rows of dataframe. I am getting memory error. I am using google colab.

This is my model :

```
model = LongformerForMultiSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096',
                                        config=config)
# Accessing the model configuration
configuration = model.config
```

[image: Configuration model image]

[image: Custom class for Global attention image]

Training Loop

```
   
for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs+1)):
    
    model.train()
    
    loss_train_total = 0

    progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train, desc='Epoch {:1d}'.format(epoch), leave=False, disable=False)
    for batch in progress_bar:
        
        #this will empty the gradients from the previous iterations
        model.zero_grad()
        
        #take out inputs
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)
        
        inputs = {'input_ids':      batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels':         batch[2],
                 }       
        #insert the input into the model and get the result
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        
        #calculate loss
        loss = outputs[0]
        loss_train_total += loss.item()

        #this will calculate the gradients
        loss.backward()
        # for preventening gradient explosion
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)
        #this will update the weights 
        optimizer.step()
        #optimizing learning rate
        scheduler.step()
        
        progress_bar.set_postfix({'training_loss': '{:.3f}'.format(loss.item()/len(batch))})
         
        
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'/content/Gdrive/My Drive/finetuned_longformer_epoch_{epoch}.model')
    #torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'checkpoint{epoch}.pth')
        
    tqdm.write(f'\nEpoch {epoch}')
    
    loss_train_avg = loss_train_total/len(dataloader_train)            
    tqdm.write(f'Training loss: {loss_train_avg}')
    
    val_loss, predictions, true_vals = evaluate(dataloader_validation)
    val_f1 = f1_score_func(predictions, true_vals)
    tqdm.write(f'Validation loss: {val_loss}')
    tqdm.write(f'F1 Score (Weighted): {val_f1}')
```

Error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-7e534d564c0a> in <module>()
     20               }       
     21      #insert the input into the model and get the result
---> 22      outputs = model(**inputs)
     23 
     24      #calculate loss

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in dropout(input, p, training, inplace)
    971     return (_VF.dropout_(input, p, training)
    972             if inplace
--> 973             else _VF.dropout(input, p, training))
    974 
    975 

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 182.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.17 GiB total capacity; 10.23 GiB already allocated; 59.81 MiB free; 10.69 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

You can check my config file and model structure and custom class for Global Attention or My complete code is on colab is here :

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19JkCht_4u6UrwcUcWNnSD2YtnsJYer0H?usp=sharing

I ran a similar code using BERT and it works without any problem.

**I am new to datascience. Please help.**

Comment: [Every time an image of code is uploaded, a kitten somewhere dies.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6664872). Have you tried a smaller batch size?

Comment: Yes. I even tried with batchsize =1 And sorry. I didnt knew about the Image Upload. From next time I will keep in mind.

Comment: which optimizer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are few checkpoints to solve this error.
Call `optimizer.zero_grad()` after `optimizer.step()`. `model.zero_grad()` clears old gradients from the last step but only if all your model parameter are in the same optimizer.

1. First VIMP step is to reduce the batch size to one when dealing with CUDA memory issue.
2. Check with SGD optimizer. According to a [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cuda-out-of-memory-when-optimizer-step/55942/6) in pytoch forum, Adam uses more memory than SGD.
3. Your model is too big and consuming lot of GPU memory upon initialization. Try to reduce the size of model and check if it solves memory problem.

**Edit:**
Longformer git repo has somewhat similar issue at https://github.com/allenai/longformer/issues/41. This might be useful if you are using a similar configuration.
[image]

Also some idea on gradient checkpoint.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did as you suggested.  I reduced the batch size to 1. I changed the optimizer from Adamw to SGD according to the post.  But still memory issue.

Comment: Is there a way to check the size of your model? you can do memory tracing to verify which block is consuming more memory.

Comment: I reduced the batch size to 1. I changed the optimizer from Adamw to SGD according to the post: . Suddenly it started working but very very slow. The dataset that i took is just 20 rows. But now i increased the input data to just 500 rows (articles). its again out of memory.

Comment: Ok. I will try to get the memory details.

Comment: Memory usage :

| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |

|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   48C    P0    34W / 250W |  16229MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                 ERR! |

Comment: I am using Transformer, Lonmgformer. I didnt added any extra layer, just using default model i guess. How can i reduse the size of that model ?  I found a similar issue in BERT : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926878/cuda-out-of-memory

Comment: check this if it is useful https://github.com/allenai/longformer/issues/41